# "Windows cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms" when installing Windows Server 2016 in a VM

Tags: installation, windows-server-2016

I downloaded Windows Server 2016 iso from the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016). The iso file size is 4.95 GB.

While installing Windows Server 2016 in VMware Workstation 2012, I see following error message.

*Windows cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms. Make sure the installation sources are valid and restart the installation.*

Please let me know, how to fix it.

Regards

InTech

Comment: Do what it said.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue installing Server 2016 on VMware player 2012. I was using the easy install and no matter how much ram or cores it still gave the error. The solution was to choose "I will install the operating system later." Then just manually set it all up from there without easy install and it works fine.

Comment: This is essentially the same solution OP linked in a comment on another answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/832411/windows-cannot-find-the-microsoft-software-license-terms-when-installing-windo#comment1065203_832457 In this case, it is the correct answer.

Comment: Ah. I had chosen the wrong option so I just exited Setup and when the VM rebooted it suddenly started working.

Comment: 2021, using VMware Workstation 16 Player and still having this issue. This was still the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That happens frequently with Server 2012 R2 and higher if the VM has a very low amount of RAM or has dynamic RAM.

Give the VM at least 2 GB (better 4 GB) of RAM for the OS installation and it should work. You can change the RAM back to what it was after the installation finished.

Comment: I did same i.e. 4GB RAM, total processor cores: 4. and 80 GB disk size. However, I see same error message.

Comment: Did you give the VM a **fixed** amount of RAM? It won't work reliably with dynamic RAM or ballooning or whatever it's called in VMware.

Comment: I fixed it by going through http://www.top-password.com/blog/vmware-fix-windows-cannot-find-the-microsoft-software-license-terms/

Comment: @EinfoMail Could you please write down your solution and accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following workaround successfully:

Install Windows Server 2016 in an Oracle VirtualBox VM, but make sure you set the disk format to `VMware compatible`.

Shut down the vm and stop VirtualBox.

Then create an empty virtual machine in your VMware environment, but replace the disk with vmdk file created in VirtualBox.

After that you will get a running instance in VMware. VirtualBox can then be uninstalled, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have selected Dynamic Memory but forgot to change the default value from 512 MB to at least 1024 MB.

So, changing the Minimum RAM to 1024 MB will enable the license terms option.

[image: Settings for Win 2016 Docker on POC Screenshot]